# No route to host exception xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, xamarin, xamarin.forms

While developing my app, today I had a tremendous problem. Everything was fine until I decided to change the icon of my app. I was doing this in the `mainActivity.cs` in the android project. 
After I tried this and had an error I tried getting it back the way it was before, but than when I tried running my project I had this problem. It would break as soon as it started. I tried debugging it but I honestly don't know whats wrong with it. I tried looking at the stack trace for an answer and I saw this :

```
01-16 19:08:50.777 D/ViewRootImpl@75e7b36[MainActivity]( 3825): 
MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1440, 2960) ci=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) 
vi=Rect(0, 84 - 0, 168) or=1
01-16 19:08:50.778 D/ViewRootImpl@75e7b36[MainActivity]( 3825): 
MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
01-16 19:08:50.778 D/ViewRootImpl@75e7b36[MainActivity]( 3825): 
mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -922408960}
01-16 19:08:50.780 V/InputMethodManager( 3825): Starting input: 
tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4575b40 nm : com.companyname.MyApp 
ic=null
01-16 19:08:50.780 I/InputMethodManager( 3825): [IMM] startInputInner - 
mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
01-16 19:08:50.799 D/InputTransport( 3825): Input channel constructed: fd=78
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
01-16 19:08:50.811 V/InputMethodManager( 3825): Starting input: 
tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@a7f8a79 nm : com.companyname.MyApp 
ic=null
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
Thread finished:  #3
The thread 'Unknown' (0x3) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
01-16 19:08:53.994 D/TcpOptimizer( 3825): [com.companyname.MyApp] connect 
failed. sid=62, mark=622, connectErrno=113(No route to host)
An unhandled exception occured.
```

I tried looking at the web for answers but nobody had similar problems with xamarin. Any idea what the cause of this might be?? I was in the last phases of developing my application. Please a little help would be consired so much. Thanks

Comment: you need to add a crash reporting tool like HockeyApp or VS App Center, or wire up your own global exception handler

Comment: Any idea what is the cause of this issue? Meanwhile I'm trying to integrate VS App Center.

Comment: What that spew is telling you is that a worker thread threw an exception when whatever code it was running failed to route a message.  [Searching the Google](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=7EVeWtTsJ43UjwPTsoGoBA&q=connectErrno%3D113%28No+route+to+host&oq=connectErrno%3D113%28No+route+to+host&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1.1394.1394.0.3007.1.1.0.0.0.0.84.84.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.83....0.vYZKtcBEhNY) with the error number and message yields some clues.  Ultimately, if you want to have a robust  app that provides crisp diagnostics, you'll need to implement exception handlers.

Comment: No.  You need to capture the exception and then debug it.